# Will hex shank drill bit fit a 3 jaw chuck?

Tags: concrete, drill, powertools, masonry

Is it possible to fit a hex shank drill bit (masonry) onto a 3 jaw chuck ?

Comment: Yes, but 3 faces of the hex bit will feel left out.

Comment: Can you provide examples? I'm confused by the question because those two things naturally mate well and are apparently designed to do so.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the shank. Some masonry bits have a round area too close to the hex to fully lock a drill chuck on (oem bits for specific brands). If the shank is a full hex it will work with no problems. I use hex bits all the time because they grip better in the drill chuck and don't take as much force to hold them in place so they won't spin when you bite into a tougher spot.

Comment: I don't think it's an accident that chucks are 3-sided and some bits have a hex shank.  It's a natural fit.